Error Trying to Replicate Database
I am getting the following errors in replication monitor when trying to do a Merge Replication between SQL in two locations

The subscription could not be initialized using an initial snapshot because one or more tables in the subscription belong to another publication, and therefore cannot be dropped. Consider initializing the subscription manually without using a snapshot. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200976)
The merge process could not initialize the subscription. Ensure that the subscription registration exists at the publisher, and reregister the subscription if necessary. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201011)

I am successfully syncing other tables in the same database to a different a server with no issue but none of the same tables that I'm trying to sync in this job.
